# CSS: How to change circle stroke filling angel (fill from the left not right)

Tags: css, animation, rotation

I'm trying to use this code to draw a circles' stroke but from left to right

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alkhoo/JwkYm/16/)

Here's the short code I'm working on now

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 300 300" preserveAspectRatio="none" style="width:300; height:300; top:0; left:0;">
  <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="57" id="grey-halo" fill="none" stroke="#dddddd" stroke-width="15" transform="rotate(-90,100,100)" />
<circle cx="100" cy="100" r="57" id="green-halo" fill="none" stroke="#00CC33" stroke-width="15" stroke-dasharray="0,20000" transform="rotate(-90,100,100)"  />
```

```
(function () {
var circle = document.getElementById('green-halo');
var interval = 30;
var angle = 0;
var angle_increment = 6;
var max_angle = 265;

window.timer = window.setInterval(function () {
    circle.setAttribute("stroke-dasharray", angle + ", 20000");
    circle.setAttribute("stroke", "rgb(80, 80, 80)");

    if (angle >= max_angle) {
        window.clearInterval(window.timer);
    }
    angle += angle_increment;
  }.bind(this), interval);
})()
```

I want to draw this part of the stroke from left to right not from right to left. How can this be done? You can edit the original fiddle and mention the changes. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should change the `transform` in circle tag

Comment: explanation please. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adjust the transfomation

```js
(function () {
    // math trick 2*pi*57 = 358, must be less than 360 degree 
    var circle = document.getElementById('green-halo');
    var myTimer = document.getElementById('myTimer');
    var interval = 30;
    var angle = 0;
    var angle_increment = 6;
    var max_angle = parseInt(Math.random()*360);

    window.timer = window.setInterval(function () {
        circle.setAttribute("stroke-dasharray", angle + ", 20000");
        circle.setAttribute("stroke", "hsl(" + parseInt(angle/360*100) + ", 90%, 45%)");
        myTimer.innerHTML = parseInt(angle/360*100) + '%';
        myTimer.setAttribute("fill", "hsl(" + parseInt(angle/360*100) + ", 90%, 45%)");

        if (angle >= max_angle) {
            window.clearInterval(window.timer);
        }
        angle += angle_increment;
    }.bind(this), interval);
})()
```

```css
#green-halo {
  transform:scaleX(-1) rotate(-90deg);
  transform-box:fill-box;
  transform-origin:center;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 300 300" preserveAspectRatio="none" style="width:300; height:300; top:0; left:0;">
      <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="57" id="grey-halo" fill="none" stroke="#dddddd" stroke-width="15" transform="rotate(-90,100,100)" />
    <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="57"  id="green-halo" fill="none" stroke="#00CC33" stroke-width="15" stroke-dasharray="0,20000" />
    <text id="myTimer" text-anchor="middle" x="100" y="110" fill="#00CC33" style="font-size: 36px;" >0%</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I really appreciate it.